# How to choose a single step method for an ODE?

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider the system of ODEs $$y'(t)=Ay(t)$$ Which is the best choice, i.e., implicit or explicit, based on the eigenvalues of matrix $A$?

Comment: Why not directly use the matrix exponential if the eigen-decomposition is available?

Answer (score 0):

If your eigenvalues have negative real parts with different orders of magnitudes, you should use an implicit method.

For a more in-depth answer, have a look at that Wikipedia article: [Stiff equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiff_equation) (it explains quite well the stability analysis for Runge Kutta methods and why explicit methods perform badly for stiff equations.)